# How to play a RTMP stream on IPhone at websites

Tags: ios, iphone, flash

I'm developing a website who needs an external RTMP stream.
I'm using [jwplayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) to run the stream using Flash (examples and information about [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming)).

My problem is the stream do not works at iOS.
Somebody suggests a solution?

Comment: To play in IOS it should be encoded with h.264. Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOS does not support rtmp protocol for that you has to use http protocols, i.e. ,http live streaming